# Implementing an eraser with paperjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, draw, paperjs

I've checked, similar questions have been asked, but have been left partially answered or not answered at all.

I need to build an eraser tool with PaperJS that will be able to erase existing paths, without erasing the image underneath.

So the image can reside on the first layer, and the paths on the second. See the accompanying JSFiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3427zft/) which shows two attempts:

```js
paper.install(window);
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

paper.setup(canvas);

//the yellow background (can also be background image) which should NOT be erased

var rect = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Point(paper.view.size.width, paper.view.size.height));
var rectPath = new Path.Rectangle(rect);
rectPath.fillColor = 'yellow';

//first attempt to erase the black line

var first = paper.project.activeLayer;

var second = new Layer();

var from = new Point(50, 0);
var to = new Point(50, 100);
var path1 = new Path.Line(from, to);
path1.strokeColor = 'black';
path1.strokeWidth = 40;

var from = new Point(0, 50);
var to = new Point(100, 50);
var path2 = new Path.Line(from, to);
path2.strokeColor = 'green'; //I've tried other colors as well, this seems irrelevant
path2.strokeWidth = 40;
path2.blendMode = 'destination-out';

//So I saw this 

var path = new CompoundPath({
    children: [
        new Path.Circle({
            center: new Point(200, 50),
            radius: 30
        }),
        new Path.Circle({
            center: new Point(200, 50),
            radius: 10
        })
    ],
    fillColor: 'black',
    selected: true
});

//second attempt
//I need to actually erase with one line through lots of paths, not sure how to implement it with this

var path = new CompoundPath({
    children: [
        new Path.Line({
            from: [350, 0],
      to: [350, 100],
            strokeWidth: 30,
            strokeColor: 'green' //irrelevant it seems
        }),
        new Path.Line({
            from: [300, 50],
      to: [400, 50],
            strokeWidth: 30,
            strokeColor: 'white' //irrelevant it seems
        })
    ],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    selected: true, 
    strokeWidth: 20
});

paper.view.draw();
```

```html
<script src="http://tmantechblog.com/testpaperjs/js/libs/paper.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas" height='500' width='500'>This does not support HTML5 canvas</canvas>
```

- The first attempt tries to use blendMode='destination-out' but it leaves a white mark rather than a transparent path
- The second implementation tries to mimic the compoundPath example provided there, but where the paths cross, no hole is produced. Also, I'm unsure how this can be used to implement an eraser across multiple paths.

Any advice on how to proceed will be appreciated. Otherwise I'll have to port my whole project either to the basic HTML 5 canvas or FabricJS, or something similar.

Comment: just another rough idea - open paths can be subdivided into more segments and their segments removed when your eraser hovers over them, closed paths are another thing altogether though..

Comment: Since I use this as a drawing app, it's not necessarily closed paths. At this stage, if the eraser is selected and dragged, I'm simply removing the entire drawn path with onMouseEnter and item.remove(). I was under the impression that removing middle segments simply reconnects adjacent segments, from http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/working-with-path-items/. Still have to try it out then. It could be a solution.

Comment: well, don't wanna spread misinformation but in case it connects adjacent vertices, I think there is a `split()` function or smth similar. All in all if this is a pixel drawing app - much like MSPaint - then paper.js might not be the *best* lib for this since it deals mostly with vectors -